# How I defined a custom function with over 100 parameters

Tags: mathematical-optimization, arguments

EDIT: To make this question clear, I am editing it again.
I'm new using Mathematica, so hope it's not a stupid question.
I have large numbers of parameters in my custom function, like e1,e2,...e100. How should I include 100 parameters in my function? Specifically, How should I express conveniently e1_,e2_,e3_,...,e100_in my custom functions,like

```
rhs1[e1_,e2_,e3_,...,e100_] :=
```

I have used Table,like

```
ff[Table[e[k] _?NumericQ, {k, 1, 100}]] :=
```

but the effect is not good.
I have tried to find some documents, but I didn't find some effective ways.So could anyone give me some advice, please?

Comment: Have you tried if your code works with  `122` instead of `2`, as you claim?

Comment: Your method to create a function of `n` using `Table` shouldn't work: Try the code with only two variables (i.e. `n=2`)

Comment: @anderstood, no, I just start to try with 122 variables. Code with 2 variables actually is my test case. So first, I should know how I can put large numbers       variables in the function instead of  input e1,e2,e3,...e122 into the function which is too time consuming.

Comment: @Mathe172 Yea, I know. I have tried Table. It doesn't work. Do you know how I can put large numbers variables in the function instead of directly input e1,e2,e3,...e122 into the function which is too time consuming. I have tried to find some documents, but I didn't find some effective ways.

Comment: @anderstood Do you mean optimizing over 100 variables is not an easy task? I know. So I would like to try first. If it cannot show good results, maybe I should try other ways to solve the problem.

Comment: @J.L. Just pass the list in as it is, i.e. `f[l_]:=...` and then call it with `f[{e1,e2,...}]`

Comment: If your question is _How can I define a function with a parametric number of arguments_, then it should be more clear and a one-line example would be more convenient than the whole complicated code (which, as I already said, does not even work with `e1` and `e2` only, contrary to what your second sentence says).

Comment: I vote to close the question in it's present form because it is not clear, and just a copy-paste of [this answer to your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/155679/18767) with a seemingly fake attempt of generalizing.

Comment: @Mathe172, Thank you for your advice. I will try it.

Comment: @anderstood, Thank you for your advice. I have edited the question again. Hope it makes the question clear.

Comment: It would be more clear if you got rid of all the superfluous code but know I understand. Using `SetDelayed` (i.e. `:=`), you can define for instance

    `f[list_] := list[[3]] + Sum[i*list[[i]], {i, 100, 122}]`

and then evaluate it as:

   `f[RandomReal[1, 122]] (* returns a real value *)`

or 

   `f[vars] (* returns a symbolic expression *)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At heart, your question is about defining a large number of variables. You can create a large collection of variables all at once using `Array`, and these can be fed into commands like `Solve`. Here is a simple example:

```
n = 5;
eVec = Array[e, 5];
Solve[e[4] == Total[eVec], e[1]]

{{e[1] -> -e[2] - e[3] - e[5]}}
```

The first line sets the number of variables (`n=5` in this case). The next line defines all `n` variables at once in an array called `eVec`. Then an equation is solved that uses all the defined variables, and (because this one is simple) it gives a fine answer. Observe that you reference single variables by part (for instance, `e[1]` is the first variable) and the collection by just `eVec`.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. That's right. Actually I have solved the problem.